# FFMPEG encoding video + 2 separate mono tracks in MXF

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mono

Having trouble converting a video with 1 video track and 1 stereo audio track.

I would like to convert it to XDCAM EX35 + 2 separate mono tracks. This is the error I keep getting.  It looks like it keeps trying to put the video track after the audio.

> Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:1 (pcm_s16le) -> channelsplit (graph 0)
>     channelsplit:FL (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le)
>     channelsplit:FR (graph 0) -> Stream #0:1 (pcm_s16le)
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (prores (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
>   Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error
>   number -1 occurred

Here is the command line I am using

```
-i "input.mov" -map 0:v -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg2video -threads 0  -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -qmin 1 -lmin "1*QP2LAMBDA" -vtag xdv3 -b:v 35000k -minrate 20000k -maxrate 35000k -bufsize 36408333 -g 15 -bf 2 -aspect 16:9 -r 30000/1001 -async 2 -map 0:a -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -map_channel 0.1.0 -map_channel 0.1.1 -filter_complex channelsplit  -f mxf -y "output.MXF"
```

Any idea what the proper command line is?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either use `-map_channel` or the [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit) audio filter, but not both, and properly map the streams:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg2video -threads 0  -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -dc 10 -qmin 1 -lmin "1*QP2LAMBDA" -vtag xdv3 -b:v 35000k -minrate 20000k -maxrate 35000k -bufsize 36408333 -g 15 -bf 2 -aspect 16:9 -r 30000/1001 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit[l][r]" -map 0:v -map "[l]" -map "[r]" -y "output.MXF"
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation - stereo → 2 × mono files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#stereo2monofiles) for more examples.

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for! thank you!